# i have a womp,womp sound coming from my left front tire

Tags: toyota, tires

It sounds like a flat but isnt. I am at a loss on what it is. just had new cvc joints put in so it isnt that. Can someone help me

Comment: If the noise is at the same rate as tire rotation, could be a tire defect, loose lug nuts, or wheel bearing going bad.  Brakes typically make a different sound.  Did it start immediately after the CV joint repair?

Comment: Could be wheel balance or uneven tire wear too.

Comment: Was the noise there before the CV Joint was replaced? Or is it new since the replacement? If it's new, I'd suggest whoever installed it has done something wrong.